# Insert into table from another table excluding a column

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table t1 (id int(5), recordnum varchar(10),claimnum float) and 
table t2( id int(5), recordnum varchar(10), Docnum varchar(max).

i am inserting the t2 data into t1 as below

```
insert into t1(id, recordnum, claimnum) 
select id,recordnum,Docnum
```

this statement executes perfectly till i have all numbers in Docnum.
My issue is i have few columns like Docnum= '0067576A887' which are not inserting and throwing me a issue.

Is there any way i can exclude this column and continue inserting the other columns

Comment: you mean inserting another rows....

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into t1(id, recordnum, claimnum) 
select id,recordnum, Docnum  where Isnumeric(docnum)=1
```

p.s. be carefull with isnumeric

it has unpredictable results in special cases.
the best solution is to use CLR function which has int or float .TryParse function...

but i think this will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, remove it from the `select`:

```
insert into t1(id, recordnum, claimnum) 
select id,recordnum,Docnum
where Docnum <> '0067576A887'
```

Comment: no, such kind of columns are present in middle , out of all the 70,000 records i insert. it will be not possible for me to point out that way.. i just showed the format like this the Docnum hav data

Comment: So you want to select which kind of data?